# What is the significance of this lemma on direct product?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, group-homomorphism

**Lemma** For a group $G$, suppose that $G = A \times B $. Then for a subset $C \subset G$, $G= C \times B \iff C = \{\alpha\cdot \phi(\alpha) \mid \alpha \in A\}$, where $\phi : A \mapsto \text{Cent}(B)$ is a homomorphism.

**Question :** Is there any way to rephrase the above lemma in simple plain english?What is its significance?

Comment: I think you'd want to mention you're using $G=A\times B$ and $G=C\times B$ to refer to *internal* direct product. (As the external direct product interpretation would be nonsense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $C$ is a "tilted" copy of $A$ within $A\times B$.

Consider the case of $A$ the $y$-axis and $B$ the $x$-axis in $G=(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$. In order for $G=C\times B$ (let's say as vector spaces so nothing janky happens) you need $C$ to be another line through the origin that is not vertical, which will be the same as $A$ but "tilted" so  that some of its elements $a\in A$ turn into elements $a+\phi(a)$. The function $\phi$ records exactly how $A$ is getting pushed to lean over $B$, and in order for the result to remain a subgroup, $\phi$ needs to be a linear map $\phi:A\to B$. (When you switch back to groups, then you need $\phi$ to be a homomorphism $A\to Z(B)$.)

Answer (score 2):

If we move $A$ around by elements in the center of $B$, the direct product doesn't care and we still have the same group.

This is definitely really imprecise, but I hope it helps with understanding what is going on.